# Does Cartodb have a function to change center location based on user location?

Tags: carto

I would like to have the map open up a the users current location. I only see documentation for setting the center on init, I would like it to be dynamic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this example](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/query_by_distance.html) shows how it can be done

add the following function to detect user location

```
// credit: http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/
function detectUserLocation(){
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    var timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      mapToPosition, 
      alertError,
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
    );
  }
  else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
  }

  function alertError(error) {
    var errors = { 
      1: 'Permission denied',
      2: 'Position unavailable',
      3: 'Request timeout'
    };
    alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
  }
}
```

if the user allows it, the above function calls `mapToPosition` to update the map to that location

```
function mapToPosition(position) {
  lon = position.coords.longitude;
  lat = position.coords.latitude;
  map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat,lon), 7);
  new L.CircleMarker([lat,lon],{radius: 4}).addTo(map);
}
```

If you want it to be dynamic, you could trigger `detectUserLocation()` from a button

```
$('#button').on('click', detectUserLocation);
```