# Showing user's location on Carto map?

Tags: carto, geolocation

I have a series of tram stops on a Carto map and would like to indicate the user's location.

Is this doable in Carto?

https://jamieparker.carto.com/builder/161cab96-859b-433d-8a72-5ae5653b1b8e/embed

I've played around unsuccessfully [Does Cartodb have a function to change center location based on user location?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152389)

Probably user error on my behalf, although Carto has changed considerably since that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a CARTO.js map application similar to the one you have shared on the second link. Do notice that [BUILDER vizjsons are not compatible with the current version of CARTO.js](https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder#temporary-limitations). So you will need to recreate your map using [createLayer method](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/api-methods/#cartodbcreatelayermap-layersource--options--callback) ([here](http://plnkr.co/edit/R9BkDg1XGheIVtFgVQs4?p=preview) you have a working example) in combination with [HTML5 Geolocation API](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp).

I create a very simple application to show you how these two things work together:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Get User Geolocation with CARTO.js</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
    <script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script> 

    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      function main() {
        // Try HTML5 geolocation
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var lat = position.coords.latitude, 
              lng = position.coords.longitude,
              query = "SELECT 1 as cartodb_id, 'You are here' as message, ST_Transform(CDB_LatLng(" + lat + ", " + lng + "), 3857) as the_geom_webmercator",
              style = "#layer{marker-width: 7; marker-fill: red; marker-line-width: 0.5; marker-line-color: white; text-name: [message]; text-face-name: 'Open Sans Bold'; text-size: 12; text-fill: #FFFFFF; text-halo-fill: fadeout(#000000, 30%); text-halo-radius: 2; text-allow-overlap: true; text-placement: point; text-placement-type: simple; text-dy: 10;}";
        console.log(lat, lng, query, style);
          var map = L.map('map', { 
                  zoomControl: false,
                  center: [lat, lng],
                  zoom: 9
                  });
            // add basemap
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CARTO</a>'}).addTo(map);
            // add cartodb layer
            cartodb.createLayer(map, {
              user_name: 'ramirocartodb',
              type: 'cartodb',
              sublayers: [{
                sql: query,
                cartocss: style,
              }]
            }, {https: true}).addTo(map)
            .done(function(layer){
            var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
            console.log(sublayer);
          });
        }); 
        } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        alert("Geolocation is disabled");
        }
      }
      window.onload = main;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can check the code and visualization [here](https://github.com/ramiroaznar/user-location-carto) and [here](https://ramiroaznar.github.io/user-location-carto/).

Comment: Thanks @ramiroaznar This is beyond my skill level but will certainly assist others.